# iOS API difference between 4.x and 5.x

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, ios5

I have iPhone 4 with iOS 4.3.2 not jailbroken.

I want to upgrade my iOS to 5.x version. If I'll do this, can I write apps for iOS 4.3 then? I mean will they work on iOS 5.x the same as on iOS 4.3? And what main differences between iOS 4.x API and 5.x?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't make any mistakes apps that run on iOS4.3 should run on iOS5 too.
And if you set the deployment target to iOS4.3 you can write apps for that version with the iOS5 SDK and the newest Xcode version too. Make sure that you don't use any iOS5 only features if you want to support iOS4

As usual apple offers plenty of documentation.

- [iOS 4.3 to iOS 5.0 API Differences](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/iOS50APIDiff/index.html)
- [iOS 5 Readiness Checklist](http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/checklist/)
- [iOS SDK Release Notes for iOS 5.0](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-5_0/_index.html)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if you upgrade your iOS you will can write apps for iOS4.3, the architecture  is the same, but some features will change, but it will not block you. The diferences can be found on apple developer web site.